# Fill a column with consecutive numbers in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `t1` in which I want to put some data from a CSV file.
To do so, I created a second table `t2` which is similar to `t1` but it's empty and it doesn't contain any constraint (`pkey` removed).

`t1.locust_id` is the `primary key` of `t1` it's auto increment but its type is `integer`, so when I want to copy date from `t2` to `t1` I have to mention the `id` in the `insert` script, here's the SQL expression I used but it didn't work well :

```
INSERT INTO public.t1(
            locust_id, day, month, year, latitude, longitude)
select max(t1.locust_id)+1, t2.day, t2.month, t2.year, t2.latitude, t2.longitude 
from public.t1, public.t2;
```

The definition of `t1` is:

```
create table public.t1
(
  locust_id   integer not null,
  day         integer,
  month       character varying(10),
  year        integer,
  date timestamp without time zone,
  latitude    double precision,
  longitude   double precision
)
```

Comment: you don't have to `insert` id column as it is auto-incremented. just insert the other columns.

Comment: why not sequence?.. and if yo uwant to join, why not join against generate_series?..

Comment: That's the problem, it is not `serial`, but it contains incremental values

Comment: I get I didn't explain it well, `t1.id` is integer but it looks like `serial`

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: The `create table` is still missing for `t1` and please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't notice, here is the `create table` statment :

`create table public.t1(
  locust_id integer NOT NULL,
  day integer,
  month character varying(10),
  year integer,
  date timestamp without time zone,
  latitude double precision,
  longitude double precision
)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what the definition of that `id` column is, but if you want increasing numbers that start after the highest number in the target table, you can use something like this:

```
INSERT INTO public.t1(locust_id, day, month, year, latitude, longitude)
select (select max(t1.locust_id) from t1) + row_number() over (), 
       t2.day, 
       t2.month, 
       t2.year, 
       t2.latitude, 
       t2.longitude 
from public.t2;
```

---

Note that your original query using `from public.t1, public.t2` creates a cross join (cartesian product) between the two tables. Most definitely that is **not** what you want.